# How do I use the state in a certain page in another page

Tags: reactjs

Basically I have a state in uploadPic component like :

```
const UploadPlantPic = () => {
   const [picData , setPicData] = useState(false)
 }
```

How do I use that state, for example if I want to do "if picData is false then do ..." in another component like "page.js" below

```
const page = () => {
       //Here I want to say "if picData is false then console.log false however I do not know how to move the state to this page
     }
```

Comment: Most standard is to use a centralised store, such as React's Context API or 3rd party one like Redux, and wrap your _entire_ app in the providers, so the data in the store is available on every page

Comment: Thank you ! I did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use react-router package hooks like this

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const UploadPlantPic = () => {
const [picData , setPicData] = useState(false)
const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate("/details", { state: { picData } });
  };

 }
```

And get state from other page:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const page = () => {
const location = useLocation();
const picData = location.state.picData
console.log(picData)
}
```